# Pass multiple function parameter by column kdb q

Tags: kdb

I'm learning kdb\q recently. I have a function declared as below:

`func_demo:{[id;time] select last synp from synp_test where instrument_id = id, tp_time < time}`

And the function works perfectly. For example, `func_demo[1;13:00:08]` will give me a single line output:

```
synp
----
7094.157
```

However, I want to pass multiple rows of data into the function, and the function  gives me multiple lines of result.

For example, I have table `t` looks like the following:

```
id     time
--------------
1     13:00:04
2     13:00:16
...
```

If possible, I want to pass in the entire `id` column and `time` column, and my expected result would be like:

```
id   time        synp
-------------------------
1    13:00:04    7094.157
2    13:00:08    8085.867
...
```

Is there a way can solve this issue? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`aj`](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj) it will return the prevailing prices if there is no exact match for time.

```
q)synp_test:update `g#id from `tp_time xasc  ([] tp_time:13:00:04 13:00:08 13:00:12  ; id: 1 2 3 ;price:10 11 12)   //
q)t1:([] id: 1 2; tp_time:13:00:04 13:00:09 )
aj[`id`tp_time;t1;synp_test]
id  tp_time     price
1   13:00:04    10
2   13:00:09    11
```

`lj` can be used in cases when we want the exact matches

Comment: Hi again... I can't perform any join command since the synp_test date is partitioned... that will shut the server dowm..

Comment: Hi, please check out the wiki - https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj ; the remarks section highlights how to join a data partitioned table.

Comment: Partitioned db:  aj[`sym`time;select .. from trade where ..;
             select .. from quote where date = ..]
Further where constraints cannot be used, or the columns will be copied instead of mapped into memory (resulting in slowdown for the aj).